# Angular Service using the AWS Encryption SDK, missing functions and access keys can't be added to web code

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, encryption

I'm trying to write an angular service which uses the AWS Encryption SDK.

I'm following the Javascript examples in this Doc:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/js-examples.html

I think the following is 'fairly' close, but there are a couple of issues.
(`generatorKeyId` and `keyIds` are dummy values as provided in the Doc for illustration)

1. The credentials variable requires an accessKeyId and a `secretAccesskey`, which look like they should be *AWS access keys*. I'm not sure what would go in `sessionToken`. Since this is an Angular / client side integration I cannot include an Access Key and Secret Key in the code as they would be publicly available. I know credentials can be inherited from an IAM Role in AWS, but that role would need to be attached to a resource i.e. an EC2 server. How can that work with a frontend application that is client-side?
2. Using the code examples from the AWS doc the `encrypt()` and `decrypt()` functions cannot be found and create compile errors. I've included the modules as described in the Doc from `@aws-crypto/client-browser` so I don't know where these functions would come from.

aws-encryption.service.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {EncryptionContext, getClient, KMS, KmsKeyringBrowser} from '@aws-crypto/client-browser';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AwsEncryptionService {
    private credentials: {'accessKeyId': string, 'secretAccessKey':string, 'sessionToken':string }
    private generatorKeyId = 'arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:111122223333:alias/EncryptDecrypt';
    private keyIds = ['arn:aws:kms:us-west-2:111122223333:key/1234abcd-12ab-34cd-56ef-1234567890ab'];

private context: EncryptionContext = {
    stage: 'demo',
    purpose: 'simple demonstration app',
    origin: 'eu-west-1'
}
constructor() {
}
generateKeyring() {
    const credentials = this.credentials;
    const clientProvider = getClient(KMS, {
        credentials
    });
    const generatorKeyId = this.generatorKeyId;
    const keyIds = this.keyIds;
    return new KmsKeyringBrowser({
        clientProvider, generatorKeyId, keyIds
    });
}
async encryptData(plaintext) {
    const keyring = this.generateKeyring();
    const context = this.context;
    return await encrypt(keyring, plaintext, { encryptionContext: context })
}
async decryptData(result) {
    const keyring = this.generateKeyring();
    const { plaintext, messageHeader } = await decrypt(keyring, result);
    const { encryptionContext } = messageHeader;
    const context = this.context;
    Object
        .entries(context)
        .forEach(([key, value]) => {
            if (encryptionContext[key] !== value) throw new Error('Encryption Context does not match expected values')
        });
    return await plaintext;
}
}
```

Compile errors:

```
Error: src/app/services/aws-encryption.service.ts:33:22 
- error TS2304: Cannot find name 'encrypt'. 33 return await 
encrypt(keyring, plaintext, { encryptionContext: context }) ~~~~~~~ 

Error: src/app/services/aws-encryption.service.ts:37:52 
- error TS2304: Cannot find name 'decrypt'. 
37 const { plaintext, messageHeader } = await decrypt(keyring, result); ~~~~~~~
```

Comment: If you want to access a KMS key from the client, it will need credentials (and you will need to overcome CORS issues too). The JS implementation is normally used in the back-end in Node.